# TypeORM use upsert with relations

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I was wondering is it possible to use upsert with TypeORM and save relations at the same time?

Lets assume that I have a table Events

```
export class Event {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  Id: number;

  @CreateDateColumn({
    type: "timestamp",
    default: () => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)",
  })
  CreatedAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({
    type: "timestamp",
    default: () => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)",
    onUpdate: "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)",
  })
  UpdatedAt: Date;

 @Column('varchar', { unique:true, length: 200 })
  UniqueKey: string;

  @OneToOne(
    () => Payload,
    (Payload) => Payload.Event
  )
  Payload: Payload;


}


@Entity()
export class ReservoirPayload {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  Id: number;

  @CreateDateColumn({
    type: "timestamp",
    default: () => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)",
  })
  CreatedAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn({
    type: "timestamp",
    default: () => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)",
    onUpdate: "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)",
  })
  UpdatedAt: Date;

  @Column("json", { nullable: true })
  Payload: any;

  @Column()
  EventId: number;

  @Column()
  EventId: number;

  @OneToOne(() => Event, (Event) => Event.Payload, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: "event_id" })
  Event: Event;
}
```

Then I have

```
const eventDto = new Event();
eventDto.UniqueKey = "alwaysunique";

const payload = new Payload();
payload.Payload = eventJSON;

eventDto.Payload = payload;

eventsToSave.push(eventDto);
```

Can i run?

```
await eventsRepository.upsert(eventsToSave, ["UniqueKey"]);
```

Note that there is no way for be to know the eventId from before because I will inserting in bulk so it might exist but it might not.

When I tried TypeORM only saved the Event entity but nothing on the Payload.

And then I notice this error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeORMError: Cannot update entity because entity id is not set in the entity.
```